# Scratch Org Capabilities with regard to EmailServiceFunction

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, apex-email-service, scratch-org

When I create an EmailServiceFunction in the scratch org and pull down to my local project I don't see the EmailServiceFunction I created reflected anywhere in the meta-data. Is this a change that can be pushed to a sandbox or production from a scratch org without an additional configuration? Is there documentation somewhere that details everything that typically is reflected in the metadata from a scratch org and can be pushed to a sandbox or production? Is this a problem I can overcome with the force:mdapi commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using force:mdapi:retrieve, you can do this.

## package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmailServicesFunction</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

## sfdx conversion

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -u scratch-org-alias -k package.xml -r .
unzip unpackaged.zip
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r unpackaged -d force-app
```

Comment: So here is the error i'm getting when i try to convert ERROR:An error was encountered processing path: /Users/davidryan/Code/NMM-DXBox-OppEmailService/unpackaged/emailservices/CognosOppEmailService.xml

Comment: @davidjryan hmm, I presumed that it would work, but doesn't seem to be supported after all.

Comment: Seems odd that there would be exceptions like this.

Comment: @davidjryan DX has to be able to parse the XML, so they probably haven't got around to it yet. It doesn't work in the Winter 19 release either.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to get back to me on this. You have been a massive help.